# CakePHP Undefined index when looking for query string

Tags: php

I get an error saying `'Undefined index: redirect'`

with this code:

```
        $came_from_site = $_GET['redirect'];
        if($came_from_site != "true")
        {
            echo 'USER TYPED IN URL MANUALLY';
        }
```

The error happens when the query string doesn't exist.... So I guess I need to check if a) it exists and then if it does b) check that it's value is true

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: $came_from_site = isset($_GET['redirect']) ? $_GET['redirect'] : null;

Comment: Hi could you explain what each bit of that line of code does as I don't understand it. Thanks ;) note: it works great by the way

Comment: The above code uses [ternary operators](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and is a shorthand for an `if/else` statement, albeit confusing sometimes, they are handy to save time and space. Read the above as: assign `$came_from_site` the return value of `$_GET['redirect']` if `isset($_GET['redirect'])` evaluates to `true`. Else, set `$came_from_site` to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($_GET['redirect'])){
    echo 'USER TYPED IN URL MANUALLY';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: use empty() or !empty() as isset() will not check the value but only existence of variable whereas empty will check the existence of variable and wether it is true,false or 0